# Network performance dropped in Ubuntu 15.04 with Realtek RTL-8110SC/8169SC

Tags: networking, 15.04

I have a strange issue with network performance. After I boot the Ubuntu 15.04 and use it for some time, the network starts to work extremely slow — 7 Mb download instead of 70-100, upload is almost not working (tested via speedtest.net). Ping also increases from standard 3ms to 70 or so.

Also the connection drops and restarts periodically.

Window 8.1 on the same machine works like a charm and I have no such problems in Ubuntu 14.10.

What could be the issue?

I'm happy to provide diagnostic information on request.

## Normal performance after reboot

[image]

## After some time using the Internet

[image]

## Diagnostics

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard [1043:849c]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
07:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet [10ec:8167] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:820d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: You have 2 network cards, which one do you use?

Comment: @Pilot6 they are both embedded to the MB. Looks like I'm using the Realtek one.

Comment: As a workaround you can try to use the other one, if there is a problem with kernel driver. Realtek wired cards have these kind of issues with linux drivers sometimes. You can `ping google.com` and see that some packets are lost.

Comment: There are no lost packets during the ping. I will try to use the other interface as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to the Intel adapter as @Pilot6 suggested in the comments and it works flawlessly. Probably some issue with the Realtek network interface driver or something.

If you have something to add here, please do so.